# append text into the beginning of a textfile

Tags: qt, qfile

Is there a way that I can always append new text into the beginning of a text file in Qt? i'm using QFile::Append to do it.

```
file.open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, see the documentation at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html:

QIODevice::Append   0x0004  The device is opened in append mode, so that all data is written to the **end of the file**.

The problem is even worse, a file is usually stored sequentially on disk, *appending* (better: *inserting*) at the start of a file would involve moving all data towards the end of the file, thus a reorganization of filesystem blocks. I'm not sure such a filesystem exists, but if, I guess it would only allow insertion of a multiple of the filesystem block size into a file.

Comment: Well, I think (not tried) that using `seek` and then writing would overwrite data in the file at this position. If you want to do that, seek to the position and start writing from there. See `bool QIODevice::seek ( qint64 pos )`. Is that your goal?

Comment: i just need to keep adding lines of text into beginning of a log file

Comment: I'm pretty sure your only option would be to rewrite the complete file each time. This seems like a bad design decision. Are you sure you don't need to append new data? Usually logfiles are growing at their end, not in their start :^)

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink your requirements: Why do you want to add log info in front of the file? Because you want your users to see the most recent info first? Do you know the unix utility tac (thats cat reversed)?

Comment: Yup. it's the requirement given to me. I assume is the user wants to view the latest info once he/she opens the file